# How to clean completely select2 control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-select2

I'm working with the awesome [select2 control](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/).

I'm trying to clean and disable the select2 with the content too so I do this:

```
$("#select2id").empty();
$("#select2id").select2("disable");
```

Ok, it works, but if i had a value selected all the items are removed, the control is disabled, but the selected value is still displayed. I want to clear all content so the placeholder would be showed. Here is a example I did where you can see the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/BSEXM/

HTML:

```
<select id="sel" data-placeholder="This is my placeholder">
    <option></option>
    <option value="a">hello</option>
    <option value="b">all</option>
    <option value="c">stack</option>
    <option value="c">overflow</option>
</select>
<br>
<button id="pres">Disable and clear</button>
<button id="ena">Enable</button>
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sel").select2();

    $("#pres").click(function () {
        $("#sel").empty();
        $("#sel").select2("disable");
    });

    $("#ena").click(function () {
        $("#sel").select2("enable");
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#sel {
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Do you have any idea or advice to this?

Comment: Title is missleading. Please change for future readers.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Why all this trouble???

use:

```
 $('#sel').select2('data', null);
```

Comment: This method has been deprecated and will be removed in Select2 4.1

Comment: Worked Perfectly! You are my angle!

Comment: it doesn't work with new implementations of select2. The answer of  Sarath Kumar it's now the working one.

Comment: what I will do if I have to keep selected option only and delete remaining all?

Answer (score 111):

Whenever you alter or change a value in **select2** try to use the trigger `("change")`:

```
$('#sel').empty().trigger("change");
```

Comment: Using empty() rather than value(null) worked for me on Select2 4.0.3, thanks!

Comment: fyi: this also removes the placeholder

Comment: Worked like a charm. \

Answer (score 36):

Try this from official select2 documentations.

version **4**

```
$("#sel").val(null).trigger("change");
```

For version **3.5.3**

```
$("#sel").select2("val", "");
```

Comment: OMG, this is it! None of the above worked for me. I guess, this solution is for Select2 v4

Comment: This did not work for me. It looks like all it changed was the size of the select box. It is now super narrow (one character wide)

Comment: @jonlink please check your select2 version.

Comment: Just to follow up. I tried it again, without editing any code, and it worked. Weird, but I'll take what I can get. Also, the docs even say to do this, so it must've been some sort of misfire :)

Answer (score 15):

To clean completely a `select2` (>= v4) component:

```
$('#sel').val(null).empty().select2('destroy')
```

- val(null) -> remove `select` form data
- empty -> remove `select` options
- select2(destroy) -> remove `select2` plugin

Then you can create a new `select2` component with the same select HTML node if you want.

Answer (score 10):

I'm using Select2 v4.0 (4.0.6-rc.0)

Using the following clears all of the values in the dropdown field:

```
$('#id_of_select2_select').empty();
```

Doing this removes them entirely and they cannot be re-selected until the page refreshes.

If all you want to do is remove the selection, do the following:

```
$('#id_of_select2_select').val(null).trigger('change');
```

The currently selected options are cleared and the user will be able to re-select their intended options.

Comment: `val(null).trigger('change')` is the way... you save my life

Answer (score 2):

As answered Sarath Kumar:

```
$('#sel').val(null).trigger('change');
```

Reference from the official documentation, here is the link:

https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#clearing-selections

Comment: I'm not sure how much value is gained from this duplicate answer.

Comment: Just added the missing reference to the official documentation. Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-  **http://jsfiddle.net/GqbSN/**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sel").select2();

    $("#pres").click(function () {
      $('#s2id_sel > a > span').text($(sel).data('placeholder')); 
        //$('.select2-container > a > span').text('This is my placeholder');
        $("#sel").select2("disable");;
       });

    $("#ena").click(function () {
        $("#sel").select2("enable");
    });
});
```

**Note**

> $('#s2id_sel > a > span').text($(sel).data('placeholder'));  What i understand looking at this plugin is the markup it creates from the select that we provide it generates id as #s2id_ + "yourselectelementid". So this would be a better way to use it in case you have multiple select controls and you want to disable only the some or one of them.

If you  want to clear the select contents:- http://jsfiddle.net/G7TXj/

Comment: It should work except, you need to remove this line `$("#sel").empty();`

Comment: I have put both the versions now.. Probably by clear he meant clear the selection. Thanks for pointing that out.. :)

Comment: Really thanks both! yes, i want to clear the contents too, sorry if i was not specific...

Comment: @Joëlle Please see my update and see if it makes sense in your case.

Comment: Ok, thats it! thanks again. By the by, could you put me a little example doing the same but deleting three select2 at the same time using its id.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this code and got the answer:

```
$('#sel').val(null).empty().select2();
```

Answer (score 0):

My select2 in first option to "all". This option clears the other options and the first option is selected

```
var $eventSelect = $("#storeList");
   $("#storeList").on("change", function (e) {
        if (e.added != undefined) {
            if (e.added.id == 0 && e.val.length>1) {
                   removeTags();
                $("#storeList").val('0').select2();

            }

        }

    });

  function removeTags(){
        $eventSelect.select2('data', null);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the doc [here](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#clearing-selections), you need to use the code as below

```
$('#mySelect2').val(null).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score -1):

try using this:

```
$('#sel').html('').select2();
```